# Nginx: client certificate authentication from different crt files

Tags: ssl, nginx, client

I configured my Nginx server as a reverse proxy to redirect reuests to my backend and handle client authentication through certificate.
First, I used this tutorial to generate my client and server .crt: https://fardog.io/blog/2017/12/30/client-side-certificate-authentication-with-nginx/ .
Once I tested that it was woking, I tried to test with my client certificates. I have three .crt from my clients so I installed just the first one on my ubuntu server (I used this link https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-ca-certificates-in-ubuntu-server/ ) and added these lines to my nginx to test:

```
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/client1.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
```

However I am having a 400 respose (400 Bad Request).
Could anyone please explain how to configure step by step nginx to validate client certificates using .crt files ? I am using nginx as a reverse proxy to my backend but I need to validate the client certificates using the clients .crt files. Thank you

Comment: Is `client1.crt` the client certificate or the CA which signed the client certificate?

Comment: It is the client certificate, BTW how can I check if it is the CA or the client certificate ?

Comment: Nginx requires the CA used to sign the client certificate.

Comment: I understand, I have the crt file of the CA. I configured my nginx server to work with self signed certificate like this : ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
However I dont know how to do for the client certificate (the ssl_client_certificate). If I import my crt to ubuntu and in my configuration I set the (ssl_client_certificate /path/client.crt) it does not work

Comment: I am debugging the nginx server to see what is the problem, and I can see the following error: 2020/06/14 14:54:27 [info] 56378#56378: *42 client SSL certificate verify error: (2:unable to get issuer certificate) while reading client request headers, client: 172.20.172.100, server: _, request: "GET /directory/TotalPendingOperations HTTP/1.1", host: "172.20.172.1:6009"